# If I shorten the length of each key name in a hash, will that shorten the read/write time of that hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, benchmarking

I'm building a large hash (~300,000 keys and values). I'm wondering if the read/write processing time of the hash will change if I have human readable key names, like: `:some_description_of_the_key` which some are around 30 characters.

Or would there be an advantage to shortening the keys to a sequenced number system (`:0_1`, `:1_1` as a rudimentary example)?

The hypothetical advantage being that each key would have a much shorter character length.

Comment: I cannot see any advantage to using those symbols because they are invalid. e.g. `:0_1 (Syntax Error)` and using them as "String Symbols" (`:"0_1"`) seems like a) it will be annoying to access; b) will bloat memory consumption since the symbols will be interned (and possibly never GC'd depening on ruby version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it would reduce the size but is unlikely to improve performance assuming your key is currently a string, number or symbol and not an object. If your key is a model or other object I recommend changing this as it does add overhead. If we’re talking about the difference between:

```
{ my_very_long_key_or_something: “”}
```

Vs

```
{ 1447 => “” }
```

Then you’re saving a number of bytes equal to the number of character reduced. So for 300k records, a saving of 15 characters each would be 4.29Mb. If you’re dealing with low memory and that kind of saving is a benefit then go for it. I really recommend revealing keys to make it understandable though.

Again, provided your key isn’t an object; your read/write issues are more likely related to the size of the value (for objects or nested hashes) or the processing you’re applying to the hash. You can try benchmarking to compare performance with:

```
Benchmark.ms { my_hash.process }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that even though RAM is cheap, CPU cache is always limited.  Depending on how Ruby stores things, if fluff dilutes data that's frequently accessed, you'll have fewer L1 / L2 / L3 cache hits.  Also, hashing a longer string is probably slightly slower, but if there's a lot of overhead on top of the actual compiled hash function then it's probably negligible.